# Как сделать так, чтобы программа в linux работала через терминал из любой директории?

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте. Как сделать так, чтобы программа в linux работала через терминал из любой директории ?

Знаю только метод через файл bashrc, где прописывается либо *alias* с командами типа:

```
alias program="cd ~/home/username/scripto/ && python OMG.py"
```

либо

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/kotlinc/bin
```

К примеру firefox у меня установлен, но при попытке открыть его через терминал выдаётся

> bash: firefox: command not found

Comment: Почему метод с `alias` вам не подходит?

Comment: Нет желания заполнять bashrc алиасами.

Comment: а `PATH` чем плох?

Comment: Создать файл со скриптом запуска этой программы и поместить его в директорию, которая уже есть в PATH.

Comment: Может нужно программу сохранять в папке usr/bin ?

Answer (score 2):

> программа в linux работала через терминал из любой директории ?

Ответ очевиден -  надо сделать так, что бы *shell* знал, где ИСКАТЬ Вашу программу. А вот этого можно достичь разными способами:

1. Наиболее канонический - разместить Вашу программу в папке */usr/local/bin*. Насколько мне известно, этот путь включён по умолчанию в $PATH во всех дистрибутивах Linux.
2. Разместить в каталоге */usr/bin* либо символическую ссылку (man 1 ls) на Вашу программу, либо крохотный файл скрипта, запускающий Вашу программу.
3. Добавить в *.bashrc* строку вида *export PATH=<Путь к вашей программе>:$PATH
4. Добавить в *.bashrc* строку вида *alias <краткое имя>='<Полный путь к Вашей программе>'

Что вам больше подходит - решайте сами. Пункт 2 требует прав root. Пункты 3 и 4 вступают в силу после перезапуска shell.